# Dar dimensiones a imagen mediante url

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia, estoy buscando la forma de mostrar la imagen con determinadas dimensiones. Por ejemplo: `width="560", height="800"`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
from io import BytesIO

root = tk.Tk()

URL = Request("https://monoschinos.com/assets/img/serie/episodio/rezero-kara-hajimeru-break-time-2nd-season-4.jpg",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
u = urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

label = tk.Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Si funciona con algunas sacadas de google pero con otras me da el mismo error HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Esto ocurre por que algunos servidores de la web tienen sistemas de seguridad que bloquean este tipo de peticiones (scraping). Puedes hacer la solicitud con un user agent de un navegador (recomendablemente [el de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)), además no es recomendado hacer `urlopen()` al link directamente.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request

URL = "https://monoschinos.com/assets/img/serie/episodio/rezero-kara-hajimeru-break-time-2nd-season-4.jpg"
r = Request(URL,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
u = urlopen(r)
```

*Esto hace una solicitud con el user agent, y **después el `urlopen()`**.*

> tampoco encuentro la manera de darle un dimensiones determinadas a la imagen y no se muestren en toda la ventana

Esto se debe por el administrador de geometría que está usando para Tkinter, `pack()` es muy limitado. Si quieres darle dimensiones especificas a cualquier widget es recomendable usar `place()` (No encuentro la documentación :().

```
label.place(relx = 0.1,rely = 0.1,relheight = 0.75,relwidth = 0.75)
```

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Comment: Gracias por responder, Le di unas dimensiones a tkinter, con geometry("600x500"), A la imagen hice con tu ejemplo, Pero como podría mostrar la imagen completa pero en demisiones pequeñas, Por ejemplo las verdaderas dimensiones son 1200x720, Pero lo muestro a 600x500 aun mostrando todo el contenido de la imagen

Comment: En ese caso creo que puedes modificar los atributos width y height del **label**.

Comment: lo hice asi `label = tk.Label(image=photo,width=240,heigh=80)` pero recorta la imagen. :/

Comment: Intenta modificando las dimensiones de la imagen antes de usar como widget. Puedes usar `resize()` de PIL.

Comment: Okey, Elimine label.pack() y puse `im = im1.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)` new_width y height con sus respectivos valores antes de PhotoImage, Corre la aplicacion pero no da la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Debes ajustar el tamaño de la imagen para que quepa en en la ventana root. Si defines `root.geometry("400x300")`, modifica `im` con `im = im.resize((400, 300))`

Comment: Entiendo, Muchas gracias esta perfecto!